# QGIS and my Network Attached Storage Server don't play well together

Tags: qgis, windows-10

I use QGIS on a desktop and multiple laptops. I store my project files on all the local computers. The project files are synced to a Synology NAS server using "Synology Drive Client" software.

I have been using this setup for years using ArcGIS with no issues, however since using QGIS, sometimes my updated edited geopackage files get overwritten by an old version and I have lost all my edits. My colleague working on the same project is having the same issue.

Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: windows 10 pro on desktop and laptops